# Expenential of times in R

Tags: r, date

I have two dates:

```
> x
[1] "2019-12-06 01:32:30 UTC"
> y
[1] "2019-12-06 01:32:49 UTC"
```

I would like to calculare the exponential of their difference:

> exp(x-y)

But I obtained the following error

```
   Error in Math.difftime(df$RootTime[1] - df$Time[1]) : 
  'exp' not defined for "difftime" objects
```

Comment: You need to convert x and y into numeric values, or directly convert into numeric their difference. Try with exp(as.numeric(x)-as.numeric(y))

Comment: Cast it to numeric: `exp(as.numeric(difftime(x, y, units="secs")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast it to `numeric` and use `units` in `difftime`:

```
exp(as.numeric(difftime(x, y, units="secs")))
#[1] 5.602796e-09
```

Data:

```
x <- as.POSIXct("2019-12-06 01:32:30 UTC")
y <- as.POSIXct("2019-12-06 01:32:49 UTC")
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to numeric before you exp

```
exp(as.numeric(x - y, units = "secs"))
```

It is best to specify units as otherwise it will be automatic. Options for units are `units = c("auto", "secs", "mins", "hours",  "days", "weeks")`

---

Calling `difftime` explicitly is optional; the `-` operators calls it.

Answer (score 1):

```
exp(as.numeric(difftime(x, y)))

# Data: 
x <- as.POSIXct("2019-12-06 01:32:30",  tz = "UTC")
y <- as.POSIXct("2019-12-06 01:32:49", tz = "UTC")
```